# GameKitServices gkDiscoveryRegisterCallback crash

Tags: ios, ios10, game-center

I'm getting crash reports from Crashlytics about GameKitServices, but haven't been able to figure out what is causing it. This is for an iOS mobile game. 100% of the crashes are on iOS 10, and 95% are when the app is in the background. The reported crash is: **Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010**. The highlighted line is: **GameKitServices gkDiscoveryRegisterCallback + 356**. I understand that the error indicates it is trying to access an object that has already been released from memory and that GameKitServices is Game Center, but I have no idea what it is or was looking for.

My current ideas are: something is being cleaned out that shouldn't when the app is going to the background; some error callback was never registered for properly; or, there is a memory leak issue since the reported average free RAM is 158 B.
Am I on the right track, or is there something else I haven't considered? Thank you very much for any help.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib    objc_msgSend + 16
1   GameKitServices    gkDiscoveryRegisterCallback + 356
2   libsystem_dnssd.dylib    CallbackWithError + 272
3   libsystem_dnssd.dylib    DNSServiceProcessResult + 892
4   libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448
6   libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
7   libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_source_invoke + 804
8   libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 668
9   CoreFoundation   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
11  CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
12  GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 100
13  UIKit              UIApplicationMain + 208
14  challenge          main.m - Line 15
                       main
15  libdyld.dylib      start + 4
```

Comment: Hey Tom, did you find the solution to this? I am having similar crash in my iOS game.

Comment: I have had no luck with this error. Best I can figure: something is being registered for a callback, but is not present when the callback is triggered.